# How to pull contacts from Google People API without being rate limited

Tags: google-api, rate-limiting, google-people-api

I am trying to pull Google contacts into my app using the Google People API. I would like to pull the initial list of contacts and then iterate through them to retrieve the email addresses of each one using the `resourceName` returned by the `connections` endpoint.

I am getting rate-limited by Google because of the 5 requests per 100 seconds per user limit.

If I wanted to pull names and email addresses for an authenticated user's contacts, how would I go about doing this? Is there a way I can do it in one fell-swoop? Are there any other endpoints I'm missing to pull Google contact information?